# How to add an input field?

Tags: angular

I'm simply trying to add an input field with a button right next to **Tab 2** as shown in my picture. So does anyone know how to do this using PrimeNG? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's [**Live Demo Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-ngif-atfssn?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<p-tabView>
   <p-tabPanel header="Tab 1" *ngIf="showTabs && showTabs['one']">
   Tab 1 content
   </p-tabPanel>
   <p-tabPanel header="Tab 2" *ngIf="showTabs && showTabs['three']">
    Tab 2 content
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: In you css make it absolute into the same container as your tabs.. then place it where you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css to implement that :

```
<div style="position: relative">
    <p-tabView>
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab 1" *ngIf="showTabs && showTabs['one']">
            Tab 1 content
        </p-tabPanel>
        <p-tabPanel header="Tab 2" *ngIf="showTabs && showTabs['three']">
            Tab 2 content
        </p-tabPanel>
    </p-tabView>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 13px; right: 10px;">
    <input pInputText type="text"><button pButton type="button" label="GO" ></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a running fork of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-52977833)

Comment: Thank you for your input mate!

Answer (score 1):

as you asked :

```
<div>
<div style="position:absolute; padding-left:11rem; padding-top:1rem;">Lorem Ipsum: 
  <input type="text" name="fname"><br></div>
  <p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel header="Tab 1" *ngIf="showTabs && showTabs['one']">
  Tab 1 content
</p-tabPanel>
<p-tabPanel header="Tab 2" *ngIf="showTabs && showTabs['three']">
  Tab 2 content
  </p-tabPanel>
  </p-tabView>
</div>
```

Here is the fork: [fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-ngif-zpqibq?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)